# Usage of SDWebImage to download and render as .AlwaysTemplate

Tags: swift, uibutton, sdwebimage

I'm having trouble setting images downloaded with SDWebImage to render as .AlwaysTemplate.  My placeholder image is set as AlwaysTemplate, but the download image will not allow Swift to apply the appropriate Tint.

I believe it has something to do with:

`image = UIImage(named: "name")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`

but I cannot figure out how to implement it into the following code.

```
    if let button = self.view.viewWithTag(3) as? UIButton
    {
      button.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://website.com/remoteimage.png"),
      for: UIControl.State.normal, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"),
      options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0)){ (image, error, cache, url) in
    }
```

Anyone have a tip to make a this downloaded image tintable?

Answer (score 3):

Use this after the image is loaded otherwise it will not work

```
 imageView?.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cache, urls) in
            if (error != nil) {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ico_placeholder")
            } else {
                imageview.image = imageview.image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
imageview.image = imageview.image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

after you set the image with sdwebimage